# C++: objects, reference to objects, reference to vector elements with and without functions - observed performance difference

Tags: c++, performance, vector, reference, double

A question from a C++ beginner, getting a headache in the early hours of the morning. Skip to the code at the bottom of the page if you want to have a look. I am applying some operations on several variables with different identifiers but the same type (i.e. `double`). the operations are either done from an external function call or within main.

I consider **6** scenarios

**(1) local objects not calling function**

**(2) reference objects not calling function**

**(3) reference to elements in vector not calling function**

**(4) local objects calling function**

**(5) reference objects not calling function**

**(6) reference to elements in vector calling function**

I got some interesting results (to me anyway). (1) and (2) took a time of 574ms average, whereas (3),(4),(5) and (6) all took approx 2.77 seconds.

I'll admit (4),(5) and (6) are probably due to the overhead arising from function call due to passing  elements in. Some questions arise to me,

- why does calculations on references to vector elements (i.e. (3)) also take the same time as calling to function? does that mean there is some sort of overhead between calling reference to vector elements, and supplying values to function which are similar? (note that the function in this case does not take `double&` but rather `double`).
- if I change function parameters all to `&double`, why does (1) and (2) take 2.7 seconds??? I mean, I'm not even calling the function to (1) and (2)! (can somebody else try this - because I found this weird)
- are there any special ways to optimize any of these, if any?

CODE: compiled with `g++ 4.7.2` with `g++ -std=c++11 -O3` on Windows MinGW.

```
#include <iostream> // c++ input/output libraries
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <vector> 

#include "timer.h"  

void do_some_calc(double aa, double bb, double cc, double dd, double ee)
{
double total{0}, add{0};
for(int tests=0; tests<5; ++tests) {
    Timer Time;
    Time.start();
    for(int i=0; i<100000; ++i)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<2000; ++j)
        {
            add = aa*bb/cc*dd/ee;
            total += add;
            aa=aa/2;
            bb=bb/2;
            cc=cc/2;
            dd=dd/2;
            ee=ee/2;
            aa=aa*2;
            bb=bb*2;
            cc=cc*2;
            dd=dd*2;
            ee=ee*2;

        }
    }
    cout << total << " with " << add << endl;
    Time.finish("func call");
}
}

int main()
{

// the numbers 12, 13,14,13 and 12 tied to a vector
std::vector<double> ch{12,13,14,13,12};

// the numbers 12, 13,14,13 and 12 tied to independent objects
double a = 12;
double b = 13;
double c = 14;
double d = 13;
double e = 12;

    // reference to objects
double& a_ref = a;
double& b_ref = b;
double& c_ref = c;
double& d_ref = d;
double& e_ref = e;

    // reference to vector elements
double& a_vref = ch[0];
double& b_vref = ch[1];
double& c_vref = ch[2];
double& d_vref = ch[3];
double& e_vref = ch[4];



cout << "1) normal without function (i.e. local):" << endl;
double total{0}, add{0};
for(int tests=0; tests<5; ++tests) {
    Timer Time;
    Time.start();
    for(int i=0; i<100000; ++i)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<2000; ++j)
        {
            add = a*b/c*d/e;
            total += add;
            a=a/2;
            b=b/2;
            c=c/2;
            d=d/2;
            e=e/2;
            a=a*2;
            b=b*2;
            c=c*2;
            d=d*2;
            e=e*2;

        }
    }
    cout << total << " with " << add << endl;
    Time.finish("obj");
}

cout << "\n\n2) reference to double obj without function (i.e. local):" << endl;
total=0, add=0;
for(int tests=0; tests<5; ++tests) {
    Timer Time;
    Time.start();
    for(int i=0; i<100000; ++i)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<2000; ++j)
        {
            add = a_ref*b_ref/c_ref*d_ref/e_ref;
            total += add;
            a_ref=a_ref/2;
            b_ref=b_ref/2;
            c_ref=c_ref/2;
            d_ref=d_ref/2;
            e_ref=e_ref/2;
            a_ref=a_ref*2;
            b_ref=b_ref*2;
            c_ref=c_ref*2;
            d_ref=d_ref*2;
            e_ref=e_ref*2;

        }
    }
    cout << total << " with " << add << endl;
    Time.finish("ref obj");
}

cout << "\n\n3) reference to double obj from vector without function (i.e. local):" << endl;
total=0, add=0;
for(int tests=0; tests<5; ++tests) {
    Timer Time;
    Time.start();
    for(int i=0; i<100000; ++i)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<2000; ++j)
        {
            add = a_vref*b_vref/c_vref*d_vref/e_vref;
            total += add;
            a_vref=a_vref/2;
            b_vref=b_vref/2;
            c_vref=c_vref/2;
            d_vref=d_vref/2;
            e_vref=e_vref/2;
            a_vref=a_vref*2;
            b_vref=b_vref*2;
            c_vref=c_vref*2;
            d_vref=d_vref*2;
            e_vref=e_vref*2;

        }
    }
    cout << total << " with " << add << endl;
    Time.finish("ref vec");
}


//cout << "\n\nreference to obj from vector without function (i.e. local):" << endl;

cout << "\n\n4) normal with function:" << endl;
do_some_calc(a,b,c,d,e);

cout << "\n\n5) reference to double obj with function:" << endl;
do_some_calc(a_ref,b_ref,c_ref,d_ref,e_ref);

cout << "\n\n6) reference to double obj from vector with function:" << endl;
do_some_calc(a_vref,b_vref,c_vref,d_vref,e_vref);

return 0;
}
```

Here is the custom `#include "Timer.h"` I created which I used here to calculate the times

```
/*
Timer class for c++11 and pre c++11 (i.e. c++03 and c++99 etc) [version 0.1]
This is currently static and does not include multiple starts
Author:
currently tested on GCC only
*/
#ifndef TIMER_H
#define TIMER_H


#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#if (__cplusplus >= 201103L)
#include <chrono>   // include new c++11 object for timer
#include <ratio>
#else
#include <ctime>    // include pre c++11 object for timer
#endif

class Timer  {

private:
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point hiResClock;
typedef std::chrono::duration<long double,std::micro> micro_t;
hiResClock store;
#else
long double store;
#endif

public:
    void start(void);                       // [c++11]  method: start     timer
void finish(const std::string& disp);           // [both]   method: finish timer

};  // end of class Timer


inline void Timer::start(void)
{
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
store = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
#else
store = (long double)std::clock()/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
#endif
}

void Timer::finish(const std::string& disp)
{
std::cout << "Time taken: ";
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
Timer::micro_t out = std::chrono::duration_cast<Timer::micro_t>    (std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()-store);
long double temp = out.count();
if(temp<1000)
    std::cout << out.count() << " micro-seconds" << std::endl;
else if(temp<1000000)
    std::cout << out.count()/1000 << " milli-seconds" << std::endl;
else if(temp<1000000000)
    std::cout << out.count()/1000000 << " seconds" << std::endl;
else if(temp<60000000000)
    std::cout << out.count()/60000000L << " minutes" << std::endl;
else
    std::cout << out.count()/3600000000ULL << " hours" << std::endl;
#else
    std::cout << ((long double)std::clock()/CLOCKS_PER_SEC-store) << " seconds" << std::endl;
#endif
    std::cout << "  For: " << disp << std::endl;
}

#endif  // instantiate Timer.h once
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not technically an answer, I would recommend that when doing performance measurements you not use the clock because at the moment you run your test, the CPU might or might not be in SpeedStep mode (i.e., running at a lower frequency to save power).

Instead, try this x86-specific thing:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter

You can use it like so:

```
#include <cstdint>

// Read the CPU Time Stamp Counter
::uint64_t getTicks() noexcept
{
     register ::uint32_t lo, hi;
#ifdef SUPPORTS_RDTSCP
     __asm__ __volatile__ ("rdtscp" // On i7 we can remove cpuid and use rdtscp
            : "=a"(lo), "=d"(hi)
            :
            : );
#else
__asm__ __volatile__ ("cpuid \n\t rdtsc" // On lesser chips there is no RDTSCP instruction
            : "=a"(lo), "=d"(hi)    // Works in 32- or 64-bit modes (don't use "=A"!!!)
            :
            : "ebx", "ecx");        // Because of cpuid
#endif
    return (::uint64_t)hi<<32 | lo;
}
```

As you can see, you will need to define SUPPORTS_RDTSCP based on what type of chip you have.

No matter what speed the CPU is running at, the number of ticks should be about the same when measuring how many ticks went by for a given instruction sequence.  Keep in mind that pipelining and out of order execution will and all that stuff will make it slightly different, but it's a lot close than using the clock stuff you are using.